# Jquery ajax: a new input field lost focus after getting focus

Tags: jquery, ajax, focus, lost-focus

I tried to focus on a new created input element during ajax update, but the focus is lost somehow.

```
       var options = {
            url: aURL,
            type: "POST",                
            dataType: "xml",
            data: params,         
            success: function(responseData, status, xhr) {
                // replace DOM element
                $(".placeholder").html(responseData);
            }
        };

        $.ajax(options);
```

Inside the responseData, there is a script

```
<script>$(function(){createInputAndFocus();});</script>
```

The script will be executed during the ajax DOM update.

```
function createInputAndFocus() {
     $(".placeholder").append('<input type="text" id="foo"/>');
     $(".placeholder").find("#foo").focus();

     // debug: check if it is focused
     console.log("active element: " + document.activeElement.id);
}
```

From the browser console, the created input (foo) is focused. But after the ajax is completed, it is not focused(highlighted) on the screen. From the console, verified it is not focused. document.activeElement is the same as the one before ajax update.

Does Jquery restore the original focus after ajax? How to focus on new input element after ajax update? I tried to set up a timer

```
function createInputAndFocus() {
         $(".placeholder").append('<input type="text" id="foo"/>');
         $(".placeholder").find("#foo").focus();

         setTimeout(function() {$(".placeholder").find("#foo").focus();}, 3000);
    }
```

Timer works. Timer is not a safe solution. the timeout might be fired too early if setting the timeout too short, and users have to wait if setting it too long. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just call the

```
createInputAndFocus();
```

straight from the success() method? Otherwise, you could try adding async=false to the options, but that may lower performance.

Comment: The DOM has been updated before setting focus. It is not a sync issue. Thanks.